# Purely Object Oriented Languages

Tags: java, oop, programming-languages

What does the term **Purely Object Oriented mean in case of Programming Languages**? Is Java a purely Object Oriented and which languages come under this category? I've often read that Purely Object Oriented languages are one in which everything comes in form of objects and so can anyone clarify the confusion.

Comment: Java has primitives, static methods don't follow OOP and methods are not objects.

Answer (score 0):

Java still has the primitives like short , int , long , float and double

these are not considered objects. However, in ruby for example everything,

including the numbers are objects.

Comment: But Java has Integer class and String class so it could be still used to create objects

Comment: Sure but the primitives like int and char are not objects.

Comment: So finally you conclude it is not Purely object oriented?

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: I suppose it's conditional... if u use all the object of classes in code without use of variables then it's Purely objected oriented otherwise no..

Comment: Good you answer your question.